# What is different between HALF_DOWN and HALF_UP in java?

Tags: java

Java Code:

```
public class BigDecimalDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                BigDecimal bd2=BigDecimal.valueOf(11);
                BigDecimal bd3=new BigDecimal("2.3");
                BigDecimal bdDiv = bd2.divide(bd3,38,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                System.out.println(bdDiv);
                BigDecimal bdDivDOWN = bd2.divide(bd3,10, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
                System.out.println(bdDivDOWN);               
                BigDecimal bdDivUP = bd2.divide(bd3,10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                System.out.println(bdDivUP);
        }
}
```

Output:

```
4.78260869565217391304347826086956521739
4.7826086957
4.7826086957
```

Question:
How come the output of RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN and RoundingMode.HALF_UP are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the javadoc of `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` says:

> Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN.

And the Javadoc of `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` says:

> Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is ≥ 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN

In your example, the discarded fraction in your second and third divisions is 0.5217391304347826086956521739, which is > 0.5, so both behave as `RoundingMode.UP`.

Only if the discarded fraction was exactly 0.5, you would see different results.

For example, the following:

```
BigDecimal bd2=BigDecimal.valueOf(11.12345678955);
BigDecimal bd3=new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal bdDiv = bd2.divide(bd3,38,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bdDiv);
BigDecimal bdDivDOWN = bd2.divide(bd3,10, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
System.out.println(bdDivDOWN);               
BigDecimal bdDivUP = bd2.divide(bd3,10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bdDivUP);
```

will output

```
11.12345678955000000000000000000000000000
11.1234567895
11.1234567896
```

Comment: You could say, for 0.5 ("half:) HALF_UP rounds up and HALF_DOWN rounds down.